# Any non-widescreen Lenovo laptops?

Tags: thinkpad

Does the Lenovo have any new 12" or 14" ThinkPad which is not widescreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All new are widescreen.  The last TP with 4:3 resolution were T60p and X61

See [this post](http://www.thinkpads.com/2009/04/15/lenovo-displays-shifting-to-169/) and [this one](http://lenovoblogs.com/insidethebox/?p=220)

Comment: That made me sad :(

Comment: Me too. In fact almost all TP users are sad :-(